# How to save event with sharedpreference in flutter

Tags: flutter

Hello I try to use this timeline package.

https://github.com/softmarshmallow/flutter-timeline

It's work fine to create timeline after press button but I don't success to save events with sharedpreference. I would like to restore history of the timeline at the initState.

```
TimelineEventDisplay get plainEventDisplay {
    return TimelineEventDisplay(
        child: TimelineEventCard(
          title: Text("just now"),
          content: Text("someone commented on your timeline ${DateTime.now()}"),
        ),
        indicator: TimelineDots.of(context).circleIcon);
}

List<TimelineEventDisplay> events;

Widget _buildTimeline() {
  return TimelineTheme(
      data: TimelineThemeData(lineColor: Colors.blueAccent),
      child: Timeline(
        indicatorSize: 56,
        events: events,
      ));
}

void _addEvent() {
  setState(() {
    events.add(plainEventDisplay);
  });
}

@override
void initState()  {

events = [

  plainEventDisplay,

  ]; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a SharedPref class so that it would be easy for you to manage things.

```
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';
import 'dart:convert';

class SharedPref {
  read(String key) async {
    final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    if(prefs.getString(key) == null){
      return null;
    }
    final map = jsonDecode(prefs.getString(key));
    return map;
  }

  save(String key, value) async {
    final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    prefs.setString(key, jsonEncode(value));
  }

  remove(String key) async {
    final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    prefs.remove(key);
  }
}
```

In your Flutter widget, create initState as follows:

```
SharedPref _prefs = SharedPref();
final events;

@override
void initState() async {
  super.initState();
  events = await _prefs.read('events');
}

void _addEvent() async {
  setState(() {
    events.add(plainEventDisplay);
  });
  await _prefs.save('events', events);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the example, but not currently working :(  no save after reload.
I forgot InitState code in my post, I upgrade what the package need.